# Applying Excel formula to a large column

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need to apply the formula =IF(Fx-TODAY()<0,"EXPIRED",Fx-TODAY()) to each row in an Excel column where x is the number of the row that the formula is in. I have a lot of rows, upwards of 100. How can I do this without manually setting each the formula for each row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set it on the first row, then drag the corner of the cell downwards, Excel will automatically adjust the formula for each row.

Comment: Glad it helped!